# using void function. is this code okay? it show no output

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop, void

using void function. is this code okay? it shows no output

I am trying to create a void function in C programming that works with pointers. I have created the following functions:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void main()
 {
   int c;
   for(;c=0;)
   {
     printf("Hello");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Try adding `\n` to the end of the string you're printing.

Comment: What do you understand `for(;c=0;)` to mean?

Comment: You probably want `int c=0; for(;c==0;) {...`, that is have `c` initialized to 0, then compare it to 0 for infinite loop?

Comment: The loop as written never executes the `printf`. It's the same as `while (0)`.

Answer (score 2):

A `for`-loop has four parts,

```
for ( init-clause ; cond-expression ; iteration-expression ) loop-statement
```

In your loop, you have an empty `init-clause` and an empty `iteration-expression`.
You have a `cond-expression` which contains the predicate that needs to be `true` for the loop to execute the `loop-statement`.

Your `cond-expression` contains an assignment, `c=0`, and in boolean contexts, the value of `c` will be implicitly converted to `true` if it's *not* `0` and `false` if it is `0`, which it is, so the `loop-statement` will never be executed.

I suggest that you move the assignment to the `init-clause` and make proper use of the `cond-expression` and `iteration-expression`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()        // make it int to be portable
{
    int c;
    for(c=0; c < 10; ++c)  // Loop 10 times
    {
        printf("Hello\n"); // \n added to get each Hello on a separate line
    }
}
```

If you don't need the value of `c` after the loop, move the declaration of `c` into the `init-statement` of the loop:

```
    // int c; // not needed
    for(int c=0; c < 10; ++c)  // Loop 10 times
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to modify the *for* loop,
`for(;c=0;)`
A *for* loop works like this, consider this example,`for(x;y;z)` for the first run, the compiler reads **x** (which is the initializer), and sees if it is compatible with **y**, if it is the loop is executed. After the loop has been executed, it executes **z**.
for the rest of its loops, it would keep repeating as long as the variable's value is compatible with **y**.
In your case, however, the condition for the loop (i.e **y**) is `c=0`, which is false, as **c** has not been given a value when it was initialized. The loop would run only if **y** is true, that is, `c=0` is true. If you initialize the variable **c** with value 0, and change the condition to `c<=0`, the code would run infinite times.

Comment: `which is false, as c has not been given a value when it was initialized` - nope, this is not a reason for `c=0` to be false